# Removing the oldest chrome.storage.sync when memory gets full?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have a chrome extension that's saving unique data in `chrome.storage.sync.set` the problem is when `chrome.storage` runs out of memory (102KB, with maximum number of items stored of 512.)what to do?

I'm thinking to add each `key` in an array and when my `chrome.storage` gets full start erasing values from the `storage` using the array but I don't want to go so heavy on the memory. is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I guess this depends on your extension. First, the array in memory may not stick around for long. Unless your extension is persistent, the background script will not stay active. It will be loaded and unloaded as needed. Can you use the local storage area instead? I don't think it has the same restrictions.

Comment: Your approach is fine assuming the key names are short. You can use LZString library to compress it further. An alternative approach is to add a timestamp field containing Date.now() to each entry. @Zack, the problem is about quota limits of chrome.storage.sync, so your comment is not relevant.

Comment: @wOxxOm As I said in my comment, holding values in an array may not work if the extension is not persistent. Not sure how that isn't relevant.

Comment: @Zack, sounds like you've assumed the array will be kept in the background script. While it would make your comment relevant, but such an approach won't work in real life where the browser/computer can be restarted. This is why I *guessed* the author was storing the array in the storage, which is the only correct implementation of the array approach which would work.